# Django settings -- could not import unipath

Tags: python, django, settings

I could not figure out what I'm doing wrong. Could you please help me?
I have the following directory structure:

```
project-repository
  \-- my-project
       \--manage.py
       \--my-project
             \--__init__.py
             \--urls.py
             \--wsgi.py
             \--settings
                    \--__init__.py
                    \--local.py
                    \--base.py
```

In the `local.py` I import `base.py`. In `base.py` I have `from unipath import Path`. When I try to run `django-admin shell --settings=my-project.settings.local` it shows me an error:

```
Error: Could not import settings 'my-project.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named unipath
```

When I do `pip freeze` it shows me:

```
Unipath==0.2.1
```

and I can easily import it in python console. Also I have `project-repository` and `my-project` on PYTHONPATH.

Here is `unipath.__file__` output:

```
/home/User/.virtualenvs/django.1.4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unipath/__init__.pyc
```

And here is one of the lines from `sys.path` output:

```
/home/User/.virtualenvs/django.1.4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Could you please point me to what I'm doind wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I figured out the problem. The think was that I did a lot of mess. I had django and other apps installed globaly (long before I started developing the project). Then I installed virtualenvwrapper and created virtualenv. Working in the virtualenv I installed the required dependencies and the django. But when I was trying to run that I ran the globally installed version of django. As a result there were some incompatibilities.
After I uninstalled global packages, everithing is ok.

How I figured out it? Thanks a lot to Jeff Knup and his post [Starting a Django 1.4 Project the Right Way](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/10/24/starting-a-django-14-project-the-right-way/). I walked through the described steps and when I ran

```
(my-virtualenv)$ which django-admin.py
```

it showed me the following path:

```
/usr/local/bin/django-admin
```

while it should have:

```
$HOME/.virtualenvs/
```

that was a sign that something is wrong.

Thanks a lot for everybody for trying to help me.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you found it helpful. It's possible to create a virtualenv with access to system packages, but that's not the default. Do you remember where you went wrong in creating the virtualenv so I can clarify in that post?

Comment: Hi, Jeff. Thanks once again. I just installed several packages globally and forgot about them. Then I created vrtualenv and installed  similar packages in virtualenv. As a result when I tried to use local packages in fact I used global ones and I couldn't understand that. So that was the main source of my problems.

Comment: Jeff if you could also clarify how to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `PYTHONPATH` to the project dir on `workon virtualenv` and remove them on `deactivate` that would be of a great value (I'm using `django-admin.py` instead of `manage.py` like it's proposed in [Two Scoopes of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/)

Answer (score 0):

add file `__init__.py` to settings directory

Comment: actually I did, but forgot to point it in the question. Thank you for noting that

Comment: Where exactly did you add `project-repository` and `my-project` to python path? You should add it in `wsgi.py` either for webserver to execute the script or in `manage.py` for the shell.

Comment: I added my project root to the PYTHONPATH using virtualenv. I try to run the development server, so adding it in `wsgi.py` is not the point.
Do you think it's connected with my-project PYTHONPATH? In fact, when I comment out the line "from unipath import Path" in the base.py, everything works perfectly (I mean the development server and the django shell).