# Django-admin.py won't find settings

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

something strange occurs on my Ubuntu 12.10. I have the following directory structure for my Django project:

```
project-repository
|__ my-project
    |__manage.py
    |__my-project
       |__ __init__.py
       |__urls.py
       |__wsgi.py
       |__settings
          |__ __init__.py
          |__local.py
          |__base.py
```

When I run from within `project-repository/my-project`

```
django-admin runserver --pythonpath=$PWD --settings=my-project.settings.local
```

everything works perfectly.
But when I try to add `project-repository/my-project` to virtualenv via `add2virtualenv $PWD` the following command

```
django-admin runserver --settings=my-project.settings.local
```

results in the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'my-project.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named my-project.settings.local
```

Although when I do `sys.path` in python console, one of the lines corresponds to the `project-repository/my-project` directory.

Could you please clarify me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred that I used the globally installed django-admin.py while trying to work with one installed in virtualenv. More details are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768107/897301.